# More apps displayed in one webpage

Tags: python, django

I would like to ask how I can display multiple apps on a main webpage. Now I have a situation that allows me to display only single app.
First app in urls file:

```
(r'^article/',include('articles.urls')),
```

Second app in urls file:

```
(r'^section_service/',include('section_service.urls')),
```

Both apps {% extends "main.html" %}

For any advice or examples I will be very grateful.

App "articles" views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from articles.models import Article

def articles(request):
    return render_to_response('articles.html',{'articles' : Article.objects.all()})

def article(request, article_id):
    return render_to_response('article.html',{'article': Article.objects.get(id=article_id)})
```

App "articles" urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^show_all/$', 'articles.views.articles'),
    url(r'^(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'articles.views.article'),

)
```

App "section_service" views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from section_service.models import Section_Service


def section_service(request):
    return render_to_response('section_service.html',{'section_service' : Section_Service.objects.all()})

def section_services(request, section_services_id):
    return render_to_response('section_services.html',{'section_services': Section_Service.objects.get(id=section_services_id)})
```

App "section_service" urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^show_all/$', 'section_service.views.section_service'),
    url(r'^(?P<section_services_id>\d+)/$', 'section_service.views.section_services'),
)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only one view can be responsible for rendering any single page. You can of course include content in that view from any app, though.

Comment: Can you tell me on my example how to do it?

Comment: No, because all you've shown is some URLs, which are irrelevant; there's only one URL pattern for a page, which points to a single view. That view needs to assemble all the information to display the page; or render a template that includes template tags that gets that information.

Comment: Ok I added the files responsible for these applications to post. Maybe now You can help :)

Comment: Daniel this mean that I need to redirect those view informations and display on the another page? What needs to be added to assemble all the information from the articles and section_service to display on another page for example main.html?

Comment: How to include content in that view from my apps?

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand what you're asking. Your view needs to do the work; it makes *absolutely no difference* if the models live in a different app, but a single view should be querying that data and sending it to a single template.

Comment: Ok when I added {% include "section_service.html" %} I can see my app, but  there is information that I write if section_service.count > 0 "You have not added component services section". Why don't show title and content from database? In section_service.html everything is correctly displayed.

Comment: Daniel look on my post images. First image is main.html site which is the home page. After the addition of {% include "section_service.html" %} to main.html, the application is displayed, but not completely. Is missing title and content. But why? When i go to section_service.html everything is correctly displayed.

Comment: **Because you have not put anything that supplies sections in your articles.show_all view**. How can I make this any clearer?